# Providing absolute path to precompiled .fmt file of all my packages

Tags: pdf, linux, format-files, mylatexformat

I had an extremely slow latex setup that took 45 seconds to a minute to compile all my packages in an empty file. As a result, I did some searching and found mylatexformat, which allowed me to create a packages.fmt file of all my packages, dropping my compilation time to three seconds when including `%&packages` at the top of my .tex file. However, when I add `%&/home/username/.latexpreamble/packages` to the top of my file, it does not work. I use my latex setup to take notes at my university and therefore have a sub directory for each class in which I need my .fmt file. Is there a way to have a global .fmt file (possibly by including its path)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Good to hear that you are healthy again. Consider upvoting/accepting helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the TeX ecosystem, system wide files are normally not found using absolute paths in your TeX file but by automatic searching in (customizable, but with sensible defaults) standard directories. If you use TeX Live, you can find the directories `pdftex` searches for format files using

```
kpsewhich -engine=pdftex -show-path=fmt | tr : '\n'
```

On my system this shows (with added comments)

```
# Search in the current directory first. Doesn't help since we want a central location
.
# This location can be used if you have multiple TeX Live versions installed and want to use separate format files for them.
/home/username/.texlive2021/texmf-config/web2c/pdftex
# This one is for automatically generated format files, you shouldn't manully place files there (it is used by fmtutil-user)
/home/username/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex
# This is a great location for custom format files for your current user
/home/username/texmf/web2c/pdftex
# Here you can store custom format files for all users on your system. The `!!` indicates that you have to run `mktexlsr` after placing files here.
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/pdftex
# As before, but specific for TeX Live 2021
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config/web2c/pdftex
# Again an automatically managed locations, this time system wide. (It is used by fmtutil-sys and therefore contains most default format files. Do not touch manually)
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex
# Theoretically for format files directly provided by TeX Live. In practice empty since TeX Live generates the formats on your system instead with fmtutil-sys. Do not touch this directory.
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/pdftex
# Repeating everything but without being pdftex specific. Does not really make sense for format files.
/home/username/.texlive2021/texmf-config/web2c
/home/username/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c
/home/username/texmf/web2c
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config/web2c
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c
!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c
```

Tl;dr: So you probably want to store your format file in `~/texmf/web2c/pdftex/packages.fmt` or (especially if you have multiple TeX Live versions installed) `~/.texlive2021/texmf-config/web2c/pdftex/packages.fmt`.

Comment: My apologies, thank you so much for your response! I got sick with pneumonia and have been offline for a bout a month. I tried out what you said and it does work. I have a new problem regarding the fmt file loading packages,s should I ask here or make a new thread. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshuaA It's generally preferred here to ask a new question if you get a new problem.